# What is this book illustrated by John Robbins?

Tags: identification-request

Is anyone aware of a list of books illustrated by John Robbins on his PBS shows?

I remember an episode in which he illustrated a story where a rabbit sought to gain antlers like a deer ("How rabbit got his horns"?); the rabbit attached some antlers he found by fixing them to his head with wax. I saw this when I was very young and I would like to know what story or book he was illustrating and the cultural significance- I'm much more interested in the author and literary style than the fantastic elements; Robbins' illustrations were haunting.  This would be in the late 70s or early/mid 80s.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to LitSE. I think this would be better as a question specifically about the rabbit / deer story, in subject and body, with a second "stretch goal" question at the end of a bibliography of all the books John Robbins illustrated on his show. Highly specific questions play to the strengths of the Q&A format.

Comment: @Bobb Seems you've made a new account - please [merge](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them. That will give you full edit and commenting privileges on your questions. Also please consider making a full account (i.e. registering) so you don't lose access when your cookies are cleared